# Creating Cordova project using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

i installed :

- -visual studio 2015
- -cordova from visual studio
- -SDK android (and installed version 25)    -installed Java SDK 1.8.121

Now, i want to create a new Cordova project and run it from Android, when i create a new project from Visual studio **(new project ->javascript->cordova)**
it creates a directory and in the solution project there are no file, but if i show hidden files the WWW direcotry appears, and it cannot run and gives me an error :**"the startup project cannot be launched"**

here what in the tool-options of cordova
[image]
what can i do?
did do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your Cordova Tools Installed or it is not installed. UPDATE or REINSTALL.

Microsoft Oficial Site: https://taco.visualstudio.com/

[image]

Some tips to work with Cordova with Visual Studio 2015.

First:
It is important that your Visual Studio is at least with Update 2 installed. (The current update version is Update 3).
You also must have installed Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova (Update 10)
You can Verify on Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio

Second:
You must create a JavaScript -> "Blank App (Apache Cordova)"
It will create a blank project.

Third:
If the error persist Clear Cordova Cache and Run Dependency Check: Tools -> Options -> Tools For Apache Cordova

Fourth:
If you are beginning with Cordova, install "IonicVS2015" using Nuget, this package will help you installing and configuring Ionic and Angular.
[image: Nuget Package]

Fifth:
You can also create a project Using Cordova Comand Tools and Import the Project in Visual Studio. It will create a file .jsproj

[image: Project]

Comment: ok thank you
i am just stuck on the fifth poing
i created a new project with CMD, created a new project cordova with visual studio and imported all files
but when run the application it gives me an error :
"unable to start debugging, the startup project cannot be launched"