# VS 2015 Apache Cordova tool Intellisense group not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Im trying to figure out a problem I have trying to get intellisense for AngularJS
The application is compiled succesfully and no errors occured
but the intellisense seems not to work
I get intellisense for basic JS libraries only
My _references.js looks like that:

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
```

Also I tried my best to fix it by looking at serval guides Which says to open tools->Options->Text editor-> JavaScript -> References and add the _references.js
Didn't work
but it seem odd when I load up the VS2015 Apache Project i get this error on the console:

```
Reference group 'Implicit (Apache Cordova)' not found.
```

Then i guess that it's probably a bug someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Verify if your VS2015 is configured for Cordova, you must install Cordova using VS2015 installer or modify it by add/remove program. In this link, you can verify if it is installed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908864/creating-cordova-project-using-visual-studio/41909418#41909418

Comment: Please check this: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/known-issues-general/ and there is a known issue: No IntelliSense is provided for Cordova plugins in JavaScript files in Apache Cordova projects. As a workaround, developers can enable IntelliSense for Cordova plugins by explicitly adding “/// <reference group="Implicit (Multi-Device Apps)” />” to the JavaScript file.